# How can I hide comment form from a poster?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a comment form and I want to hide that comment form from the 
   author of the post. I want author not to be able to comment their own posts.

```
   <h3>Add a Comment</h3>


 <%=simple_form_for([@post,@post.comments.build]) do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_area :content,:maxlength=>"6000", label: ".",:rows => 
     6,:cols => 75,class: "form-control" %>
    <%= f.submit"Publish", :title => "content can't be blank", :rel => 
    'tooltip',class: "btn btn-md"%>
        </div>
       <% end %>
```

Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <% unless @post.user == current_user %>

     <%end%>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have a belongs_to relationship, wrap the form in something like:

```
<% unless @post.user == current_user %>

  # form here

<% end %>
```

You want to add a validation to the model as well; ensure that no comments are saved where the comment author and the post author are the same.